# iOS comparing two same NSDates does not return NSOrderedSame

Tags: ios, nsdate

As the title, I have tried the following simple code:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];
if([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame)
 NSLog(@"two time same");
else
 NSLog(@"two time not same");
```

and the result is:

```
two time not same
```

I don't understand that, can someone give me some tips? Thank you.

Comment: The dates are not the same.

Answer (score 9):

it's not same because there is a little time difference of creation of object, just try to print there value in `NSTimeInterVal` to know better.

Example:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"date1 : %f", [date1 timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSLog(@"date2 : %f", [date2 timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

Output:

```
date1 : 1404466511.638555
date2 : 1404466511.638558
```

and you also can see the difference using method

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

Comment: Added an example just to illustrate the difference.

Comment: Ok,thanks very much, i not pay the attention to accuracy of the nsdate. Thanks you again